# lightning-datatable sortBy example doesn't handle undefined values

Tags: javascript

I understand this is more of general JS question, but being part of of lwc component lib it's worth posting here.

The function they use is rather clever and I can't really figure out myself (I did had this issue  before tho).

Please see [this playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/4ES2xn82h/1/edit) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter a condition check for null and where to place them if null like this

```
  if (a ==null) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (b == null) {
        return -1;
    }else{
            return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));}
 };
```

here is a pg https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/4ES2xn82h/3/edit

Comment: Good start, but how do you get undefined ones to be either on top or bottom, not always on bottom?

Comment: @dzh you can put them either on top or bottom just replace "return 1" with "return -1" and vice versa